# NPM version 2 error when installed version is version 8

Tags: node.js

I have installed the latest version of NodeJS and the latest version is version 8.4.0

I tried creating a react-app but it keeps creating in version 2.

Why ? How do I recify this ?

Comment: The current LTS version of nodejs is 16.xx, so unless you haven't touched your system for quite some years, I doubt you have installed nodejs 8.4. Please add the output of `node --version` and `npm --version` to your question. And *what* is of "version 2"?

Comment: You should upgrade the Node version and that is 16.xx

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of nodejs is

```
Latest LTS Version: 16.13.2 (includes npm 8.1.2)
```

According to https://nodejs.org/en/download/

This happens in linux when you try to install node with default package manager.

To fix this uninstall nodejs.
Then execute the following command :

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Read more here : https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions